# Accidentally delete all my files using git command

Tags: git

I didn't realize this would delete everything:

```
git clean -d -f -x
```

How do I recover the lost files after the command above?

edit:

my setup is virtualbox with ubutu as a virtual machine. I've deleted everything outside of the repo from my home directory :(((

Comment: If you are on Linux and have filesystem which supports undelete, remount partition with your repository into read-only mode as soon as possible. Then try to recover them, using e.g. extundelete.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

http://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_from_accidently_deleted_files_or_crashed_drives_in_ubuntu

and then use search monkey to find the files

Answer (score 5):

Invoking `git clean` removes all files that are not controlled by git - meaning they were not committed before.
Therefore they were not stored in repository at all, and cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't delete everything; it only delete untracked files (the ones that aren't in the repository).

`git` can't possibly restore files that aren't in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

There is no recovering files after using `git clean` in your repository.